# Joining the row of table with column of another table

Tags: sql

I have a requirement, where I need to write a query to identify mandatory fields in one table (Mapping Table) and then use this information to check in another table (Employee Table) if mandatory fields exist, if they don't I need to throw an error with the help of stored proc.

Mapping Table

| FieldName | Mandatory |
| --- | --- |
| EmployeeName | Y |
| EmployeeNum | Y |
| EmployeeAddress | N |

The query should check the Mapping table and Employee table, if field is mandatory in mapping table it should have values in Employee else should throw the error.

I understand, during the schema creation of Employee, I can define the fields as not null. However, for some reasons this does not work some times

**Edit:** Employee Table Structure

| Column Name | Data Type |
| --- | --- |
| EmployeeName | varchar(200) |
| EmployeeNum | int |
| EmployeeAddress | varchar(200) |

Comment: This is just `SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE EmployeeName IS NULL OR EmployeeNum IS NULL`, right?

Comment: Not this simple. Query firstly needs to look into mapping table, if field is mandatory in mapping table then it should check this IS NULL condition in Employee Table

Comment: Can you tell the fields of Employee table? Does any of them have foreign key of another?

Comment: Structure is added in edits.

Comment: What do you mean with mandatory?  not null, not null and not the empty string or a particular value for the int  or if the column is present in the target table?  If the latter you need to look at meta information in information_schema if your database supports it, or you need to construct a query that reference the mandatory fields and catch if the query fails. For these types of questions it's very helpful to include example data that did and didn't work as expected.  Add a tag for the database you use.

Comment: I don't have access to information_Schema. Need to understand how this mapping table and the actual table can be joined. Because mapping table contains field information in row form. For eg. If I need to check if EmployeeName column is mandatory or not I will get the information from mapping table and then if it is mandatory it will check not null in employee table

Comment: I still don't understand what mandatory means.  You join data but for the Employee table it's meta-data.  If you need to check if the column exist then the best you can do (without access to the information_schema)  is generate queries that reference those mandatory columns.  The query will fail if the column is missing: `select * from Employee where EmployeeName is null or EmployeeName is not null limit 1`.

Comment: You can write a query to generate those queries from your mapping table: `select 'select * from Employee where ' || FieldName || ' is null or ' || FieldName || ' is not null limit 1' from Mapping where Mandatory = 'Y';`.  You then execute this dynamic query.

Comment: Right.  You can't "join" a field from one table and a column name in another table.  This would be easy if you were driving SQL from a programming language.

Comment: What's wrong wth just using contraints on the `Employee` table then you don't need to be checking and handling data errors.

Comment: @AllanWind, thanks this worked from me. There is a minor change however, instead of adding pipe (||) as concatenation, I added (+) for concatenation.

Comment: @Stu, the reason why I cannot put constraint on Employee table, because it will be used by multiple applications. For few applications Address can be a mandtory field whereas for other Address can be an optional field. I hope this make things clear to you.

Comment: @VBIN It's database specific and you haven't told us what database you are using.  Let me write that up as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to check meta-data then you usually query the information_schema.

Otherwise your only option it write a query that reference the mandatory field, and if the field is not present the query will fail.  Here is a dynamic query that generates (`FieldName`, `Query`) that you need to iterative over if `Query` fails then you know `FieldName` is missing:

```
select
   FieldName,
   'select * from Employee where ' +  FieldName + ' is null or ' + FieldName + ' is not null limit 1'
from Mapping
where Mandatory = 'Y');
```